# Custom product tab in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, tabs, product-page, magento2.3.1

I have my custom module to create tabs in product page.
In magento 2.3.0 works perfectly, but after update Magento to 2.3.1 my module doesn't work. 
are there any big changes in magento wersion??

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: Check what class you're extending. I had a few issues with new classes which I had to extend from in some of my modules.

Comment: can you please share screenshots and code?